# Why did the account sync became so delayed specifically for the Google account?

Tags: sync, gmail, google-account, push-notifications, nokia-9

Until recently Gmail messages arrived to my Nokia 9 PureView instantly.

But recently unacceptable sync delays appeared in the Google account, especially in popular services like Gmail.

Nokia suggested to delete Gmail's cache and do a soft reboot (power+volume up), but it didn't help whatsoever. Likewise neither did Safe Mode. Their next suggestion - factory reset - was enough to send me here.
If I manually click the 3 dots and choose to sync now, it solves it...for that moment.

The following screenshot was taken at 18:30, almost half a working day after some of these syncs took place.
WhatsApp, in comparison, syncs its contacts every hour without any misses.

Can anything bring back the Google Account sync to what it used to be?

[image: account sync delayed]

Comment: Are push notifications of other apps also delayed? If yes I would suspect that the GooglePlayServices may not work correctly. Therefore this is the app you should try clearing the cache.

Comment: No, WhatsApp and other apps are still immediate. Clearing GooglePlayServices's cache didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's [Fix sync errors with the Gmail Android app](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2650727)'s last resort ("Only follow these steps if the above steps didn't work") solved it for me!

However, it initially led to confusion since it seems to refer to obsolete settings.

The **correct** "last resort" steps are:

1. Open your device's **Settings** app.
2. Tap **Apps & notifications** > **See All Apps** (not "App info").
3. Tap **Gmail** > **Storage & cache** (not "Storage").
4. Tap **CLEAR STORAGE** > **OK** (not "Clear Data").
5. Restart your device.

Not sure step #5 is mandatory, but I guess it's better to be on the safe side.

Comment: _"CLEAR STORAGE > OK (not "Clear Data")"_ so clear cache then?

Comment: True, just meant Google's outdated guide calls it "Clear Data" instead of "Clear Storage".